# Вывод информации в консоль и в терминал отличаются друг от друга

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, вывод, git-cmd

Пишу небольшую библиотеку протокола для обработки информации по модбасу. Так как библиотека сама по себе уже написана для передачи и считывания информации я использую boost а точнее asio::serial_port io. У меня есть функция которая пишет и читает данные по компорту. Ниже приведен кусок кода который читает информацию с компорта и должна выводить полный пакет в консоль , просто для отладки:

```
read_values_DAC_client *Sender::listener(read_values_DAC_master *pack)
{
std::cout << "listener dac_client" <<std::endl;
io_service io;
serial_port port(io);
port.open(namePort);
port.set_option(serial_port_base::baud_rate(115200));
unsigned char c[13];
read(port,buffer(c,13));
port.close();
uint16_t szD = c[11];
unsigned char *buffPack = new unsigned char[13 + (int)szD + 2];
for (int i=0;i<13;i++)
{
    buffPack[i] = c[i];
}
read(port,buffer(buffPack+13,(int)szD+2));
if (printCRC2Pack(buffPack,(int)szD))
{
    for (int i = 0; i<13; i++)
        printf("%x", buffPack[i]);
    if ((int)buffPack[11] != 0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<(int)buffPack[11]; i++)
            printf("%x",buffPack[12 + i]);
    }
    uint16_t szD11 = *((uint16_t*)&buffPack[11]);
    printf("%x", buffPack[13 + (int)szD11]);
    printf("%x", buffPack[14 + (int)szD11]);
    printf("\n");

    return (read_values_DAC_client*)buffPack;
}
else
    std::cout << "Incorrect data obtained as a result of CRC 
    counting<<std::endl;

return NULL;
}
```

Главный вопрос -  если я открываю приложение в консоле CMD(Windows) то вывод происходит правильно, а точней выводит пакет в консоль. А если я запускаю приложение в терминале git то вывод пакета происходит после завершения программы , с чем это связанно? я совсем не понимаю.

Comment: А что за значение сидит (может сидеть) в байте 12? Почему вы так смело берете два байта (11 и 12) как двухбайтовое целое `szD11`, добавляете к ним 13 и 14 и лезете по этому индексам в массив? Это значит, что байт 12 может быть только 0 или 1? И если он 1, то байт 11 заведомо равен 255? Или замысел в чем-то другом?

Comment: @AnT так как пакет может быть разного размера там лежит количество байтов в поле data. Который динамический, вот пример пакета 
typedef struct {
     struct package header;
     uint8_t status;    // Статус выполнения
                               // 0 - выполненно
                               // 1-255 - код ошибки
     uint8_t startPos;  // Номер первого из читаемых (A,D)
                                 // число читаемых (A,D) вычисляется
                                 // из длинны пакета (len = 2*N+2)
     uint8_t errPtr[0];
}read_values_DAC_client;

Comment: Где именно "там" лежит количество байтов? В [11] или в [11-12]? Я имею в виду ситуацию, когда, скажем, [11] содержит 15, а [12] содержит 1. Такое может быть или нет? В этом случае `szD` у вас будет равно 15. Вы выделите 30 байт памяти под буфер. А потом `szD11` будет равно 271 и вы полезете в этот буфер по индексам [284] и [285]. Что неверно в этих моих рассуждениях?

Answer (score 0):

При направлении вывода программы в файл (или на вход другой программы), политика буферизации вывода отличается от данной политике при выводе в консоль. 
Для того чтобы быть уверенным что вывод действительно произошел, нужно сбросить соответствующие буфера вывода, после соответствующего вывода.

```
std::cout.flush() ; // если выводили в поток
fflush(stdout); // если использовали printf
```

Comment: так почему это отличается из за разных консолей ?

Comment: @АнтонИгнатьев просто сбрасывайте буфер. std::endl кстати тоже сбрасывает буфер. А ещё не рекомендуется использовать совместно printf и std::cout

Comment: @АнтонИгнатьев  Про вторую консоль CRT не понял, что это консоль, и счел взаимодействием с другой программой. Вероятно, git запускает дочерний процесс не через `system()`.